# How node.js handles thousands of requests at the same time? Should other client need to wait?

Tags: node.js, express, server

How node.js handle thousands of requests when the server is busy handling big operations per request? Should other clients need to wait until the server finished operation per request?
In the example below, after I call `/big` server resources will be busy totally. And if I call `/small` immediately how can I get a response as it's a single thread operation.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/small', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('posts');
});

app.get('/big', (req, res, next) => {
  console.time('test');
  for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
  res.send('comments');
  console.timeEnd('test');
});

app.listen(5555, '127.0.0.1', undefined, () => {
  console.log(`Listening to port 5555`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

NodeJs works asynchronously with single threaded multi worker in background. Node JS applications uses “Single Threaded Event Loop Model” architecture to handle multiple concurrent clients. So client do not need to wait for the prior request to complete.

It uses callback instead of conventional "return". You can read Async await for more detailed information.
for better understanding you can watch this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsjrN-T3ZCs